# Docker plugin in IntelliJ Idea "Can't locate certificate files under ..."

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I have a remote docker instance running on port 2376 as described in the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) and I can successfully connect to it via console with the command

```sh
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=vm-ca.pem \
       --tlscert=vm-client-cert.pem \
       --tlskey=vm-client-key.pem \
       -H=10.38.105.34:2376 ps
```

Now I'm trying to use **IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2020.2** to connect, but I cannot use the TLS connection because of the error

> Can't locate certificate files under C:\Users\marco\certs

Inside that folder there are the certificates used in the successfully previous command.
What am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share full idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov there isn't any log about the issue. I guess is generated by the docker plugin, not by intellij, but i'm not sure about it

Comment: @y.bedrov ooh dude, my bad. The certs **have to be named** ca.pem, client.pem, key.pem. No other name works. Via CLI I can specify the names, but not in Intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certs **have to be named** `ca.pem`, `cert.pem`, `key.pem`, no other name works.

Comment: Used your solution, but had to rename `client.pem` to `cert.pem`